# How to track which file adds a path in PATH?

Tags: bash, path

Something adds an undesired path to my `PATH` environment variable.

**How can I find the culprit?**

I've already looked at:

- ~/.bashrc
- ~/.bash_profile
- /etc/bashrc
- /etc/profile
- /etc/environment

Comment: Have you looked at the files in `/etc/profile.d`? Is there any other software on the system that edits environment variables such as this: https://github.com/cea-hpc/modules?

Comment: Yes, nothing... It's basically PATHs of applications I've installed using `yum/rpm`.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe an overkill, and you should (of course) attempt to find it by tracing the order of running scripts, but there are times when that tree becomes way to difficult to parse. So it is possible to simply grep for it:

```
grep --regexp='PATH=.*/path/that/you/try/to/find' --binary-files=without-match -r /
```

Please note, that this is a very long process, and your harddrive will be going wild throughout (you are basically reading every text file that you have).

Comment: I've tried it already but get `grep: memory exhausted`. That's funny bash/terminal/terminator isn't able to list all scripts it loads.

Comment: can you make sure that you exclude binary (as shown above) and also change `*` to `\{0,100\}` in regex?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
grep -rF --binary-files=without-match ':/the/undesired/path' / 2> /dev/null
```

If `/the/undesired/path` is `$UNKNOWN_VARIABLE_NAME_FOR_THE_UNDESIRED_PATH` or , this will obviously not work.

Note that `/home/user/undesired/path` will often be assigned as `$HOME/undesired/path`.

Run the same without `:` to also get variable assignments:

```
grep -rF --binary-files=without-match '/the/undesired/path' / 2> /dev/null
```

If that doesn't work, find all `PATH` assignments and filter manually:

```
grep -rwF --binary-files=without-match 'PATH=' / 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate file finding and searching with `find` and `xargs`, see `man` pages for each.

```
sudo find / -type f -print0 | \
   xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty \
       grep -l 'PATH'
```

to list all filenames that mention PATH. Append

```
| xargs less
```

to look at the files.

One can't search for `/some/deep/path/bin`, because it could be expressed as `$SDP/bin`, for all we know.

Comment: That gives thousands of files.